# MongoDB: return just the document from an array that matches a certain query (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection in the form of:

```
users: {
    {
        user_id: 1000,
        activities: [
           {id: 1, activity: 'swimming'},
           {id: 2, activity: 'running'},
           {id: 3, activity: 'biking'},...
        ]
    },...
}
```

and I want to get the activity document that matches a specific ID. For example, if I query using `{id: 1}`, I want an output of `{id: 1, activity: 'swimming'}`. Currenlty, I'm trying to use `findOne({activities: {$elemMatch: {id: 1}}})`, but it returns the entire user document (the user id, and all the activities).

The code I'm using is:

```
id = req.body.queryID;
db.collection('users').findOne({activities: {$elemMatch: {id}}})
    .then((document) => {
        console.log(document);
        // more code after this
    });
```

I've also tried to query using `aggregate()` and `findOne({}, {activities: {$elemMatch: {id}}})`, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I am on MongoDB version 4.4.8 according to `db.version()`. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If the `document` contains all the information you want, then filtering the specific data from it may suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts look close, I think you just need to put them together. [`findOne`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) takes two optional arguments, a query and a projection. The query tells MongoDB what document to look for and return. The projection document tells MongoDB what field(s) to include in the document returned by the query.

What you have here:

```
db.collection('users').findOne({ activities: { $elemMatch: { id }}})
```

Passes one argument, the query. It will look for a document where there is one element in the `activities` array with an `id` equal to the value of the variable `id`. You could also write this as:

```
db.collection('users').findOne({ "activities.id": id })
```

You'd also like to only return documents in the `activities` array with a matching ID. This is when you'd do something like your other attempt, where `$elemMatch` is in the second argument, the projection:

```
db.collection('users').findOne({}, {activities: {$elemMatch: {id}}})
```

But because you passed an empty query, MongoDB will return any document, not necessarily one that contains an activity with a matching ID.

So if you pass both a query and the projection, I think you should get what you're looking for. It might look like this:

```
db.collection('users').findOne({ "activities.id": id }, { activities: { $elemMatch: { id }}})
```

This will include only the `_id` field and the matching `activities` document if one exists. If you want to include other fields of the document, they need to be explicitly included. See [this documentation about projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#projection).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `aggregate` method with the `unwind`, `match` and `project` pipelines

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$activities"},
    {$match: {"activities.id": id}},
    {$project: {id: "$activities.id", activity: "$activities.activity", _id: 0}}
])
```

NOTE: This code is written using the mongo shell syntax.

The query does the following

1. starts with the `unwind` pipeline which first pulls out all the items in the activities array.
2. The `match` pipeline finds the array element that has the id we're looking for
3. The `project` pipeline returns the output as desired

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follow:

```
db.users.aggregate([
      {
        '$unwind': '$activities'
      }, {
        '$match': {
          'id': id
        }
      }, {
        '$project': {
          'activity': '$activities.activity', 
          'id': '$activities.id',
          '_id':0
        }
      }
    ]);
```